# Cannot start Jmeter GUI. Error : "Must use the serial GC in the DCEVM"

Tags: jmeter-5.0

I am having trouble starting the GUI of apache Jmeter.

Once i double click on the jmeter.bat file, the command prompt opens and i get the following error:

Must use the serial GC in the DCEVM
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
errorlevel=1
Press any key to continue . . .

Any ideas?

P.S. My goal is to run jmeter to make some concurrent requests to a REST service of mine. If you have any other ideas, on how to make this simulation, they are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue caused by the GC (garbage collection) settings defined by default in the script you are running to launch JMeter, when also using DCEVM with your JVM (DCEVM does not support G1GC). To work around it, you can override the default GC settings by defining the environment variable

> GC_ALGO="-XX:-UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100
> -XX:G1ReservePercent=20"

in your shell and running the launch script again. The only difference between these values and the default is replacing `+UseG1GC` with `-UseG1GC`

Further details can be seen at https://douglascrp.blogspot.com/2017/07/smartgit-with-hotswapagent-enabled.html